# Probability that Path from A to B is Closed

Tags: probability

Suppose a man wants to walk from A to B, where there are 5 bridges that have a probability of being broken or not (all independent from one another).

[image]

The probability of each bridge being not broken is given by $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4,P_5$, respectively. What is the probability that the man can walk from A to B?

My logic here is to consider each of the different paths that can be taken. Notably, the following paths can be taken:

$Z_1 = 1-4$, $Z_2= 2-5$, $Z_3 = 1-3-5$ , $Z_4= 2-3-4$

Then the probability that each path Z can be taken, since they are independent, is given by:

$P(Z_1)= P_1 \cdot P_4$ , $P(Z_2)=  P_2 \cdot P_5$ , $P(Z_3)= P_1 \cdot P_3 \cdot P_5$ , $P(Z_4)= P_2 \cdot P_3 \cdot P_4$

So  the probability that none of the paths can be crossed is given by:
$$P(None) =P(Z_1)\cdot P(Z_2)\cdot P(Z_3)\cdot P(Z_4)$$
And therefore at probability that at least one path can be crossed is given by:
$$P(A to B) = 1-(P(Z_1)\cdot P(Z_2)\cdot P(Z_3)\cdot P(Z_4))$$

Is this logic wrong? If so where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. Note that if $P_1$ is out, you are given that $Z_1$ and $Z_3$ are false, so these events are not really independent, since if $Z_1$ is false, there is a higher chance $Z_3$ is false.

One trick is to stick to edges.

Assume $P_1$ is false. Then only possibilities are $Z_2$ and $Z_4$, so if $P_2$ is true if there must exist a path. The rest are independent, so you win when $P_3 \cdot P_4$ or $P_5$ are true. This case then must have the weight of $$(1 - P_1) P_2 (P_3 P_4 + P_5).$$

Now assume $P_1$ is true. If $P_4$ is false, then both $P_3$ and $P_5$ must be true. If $P_4$ is true, you are done. So the weight of this case is
$$P_1 \left(P_4 + (1-P_4) P_3 P_5\right).$$

Finally, combine both cases (they are non-intersecting hence the weights add) and do arithmetic.

Comment: For the last part, where if P4 is false, then shouldn't it be P3 and P5 that must be true, not P2 and P5? If I do it that way then it makes sense.

Comment: @BrydenC yes, typo, fixed

Answer (score 1):

You have made a mistake in calculating $P(None)$. It should be calculated as (keeping the variables from the question),
$$
P(i,j) = P(\text{bridge i being selected})*P(\text{bridge i not broken})* \\P(\text{bridge j being selected})*P(\text{bridge j not broken})
$$
Here $P(i,j)$ represent the probability of taking the bridge i, then j.

$$
P(None) = P(1,4)+P(2,5)+P(1,3,5)+P(2,3,4) \\
P(none) = (1/2*P_1*1/2*P_4)+(1/2*P_2*1/2*P_5)+\\ (1/2*P_1*1/2*P_3*1*P_5)+\\(1/2*P_2*1/2*P_3*1*P_4)
$$

$P(\text{bridge 1 being selected at start}) = 1/(\text{total number of options}) = 1/2$
$P(\text{bridge 4/5 selected when you travelled from 3}) = 1$

And hence the probability that at least one path can be crossed is given by:

$$
P(AtoB)=1−P(None)
$$

Here I have made the assumption that, the man is not allowed to walk a bridge twice and he doesn't move from right to left.